# Extract Font from PDF using GdPicture

Tags: pdf, fonts

According to their website (http://www.gdpicture.com/products/managed-pdf/) you have the ability to extract fonts from a PDF file. However, I can't seem to find the functionality to do this. I have encountered several methods to add them, but none to extract them (and they don't show as embedded files). Has anyone tried to do this, or have experience with GdPicture?

Version: 14 (Current)

Answer (score 0):

Disclosure: I am part of the ORPALIS technical staff that edits the GdPicture.NET SDK, that's why I know there's an ongoing communication about this already.

It is my understanding that you have a support case open for a merging issue relative to fonts and as you know, our development team is currently working on a fix that will solve it so I strongly recommend that you wait for them to finish.

There's no extraction of the embedded font as you might expect at the moment but the development team is also working on one, we will let you know as soon as it is available (it should be very soon).

You can get information about (already) embedded fonts using the GetFontCount, IsFontEmbedded, GetFontName and GetFontType methods.

You can also add new embedded fonts (of different types) using the AddFontFromFileU, AddStandardFont, AddTrueTypeFont, AddTrueTypeFontFromFile, AddTrueTypeFontFromFileU and AddTrueTypeFontU methods.